# Why does this material crash Blender 2.81a Eevee on OS X El Capitan

Tags: node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine, bump

FYI: this on OS X El Capitan with Blender 2.81a.

I copied the attached material from a youtube tutorial for Blender 2.80.  I made some modifications to the original, but the only stickler seems to be the Bump map.  Every time I connect the Bump map normal output to to the shader's normal input, Blender goes off to beachball land.  Seems to work fine in 2.81a Cycles.

Is there something I'm missing or a bug I don't know about?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't crash for me with Eevee in 2.81a. Try to update your graphics driver and if that doesn't fix the issue, post a bug report through *Help > Report a Bug*.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but I'm on Mac.  Can't update graphics driver.  I'll fix my post to reflect OS X.

Answer (score 1):

OS X El Capitan (10.11) doesn't meet the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for Blender 2.8x. You need macOS 10.12 or later and a supported GPU.

> Blender is cross-platform, it runs on every major operating system:
>
> - **Windows 10, 8 and 7**
> - **macOS 10.12+**
> - **Linux**

Comment: Didn't know that, my apologies.  I tried the same thing on 10.13 with 2.81a and it works fine.